# How to print Multiple .HTML documents in vb.net

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, printing, document

My application creates multiple .html documents( bills ). i need them to send it to a printer. i used following code.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvPrintList.SelectedRows
    If (File.Exists(row.Cells("FileName").Value.ToString)) Then
        Dim wbPrintTemp As New WebBrowser
        wbPrintTemp.Url = New Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}", row.Cells("FileName").Value.ToString))
        wbPrint.Print()
    End If
Next
```

I have more than 100 documents in the loop, it won't send all of them to printer. it sends 50 or 55 or sometimes 60. 
Can someone help me here.

1. should i have to wait till the document gets loaded into the web
   browser? if yes how to use document loaded event?.
2. how to wait till the printer completes the printing?

Comment: This is an educated guess but what happens if you use a single `WebBrowser` control, call `Navigate` and handle `DocumentCompleted` and call `Print` there and then call `Navigate` again?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Document completed event helps for my 1st question.
but loop runs faster and printer is not taking all the documents i send. that's where i wanna know how to wait till the printer completes the printing?